# Reusable Swift extension and selectors

Tags: ios, swift, macos, selector

Does exist any solution to make reusable protocol extension for more classes with selectors which would point to itself?
For example I am trying to make extension `TimerHelper` which adds appropriate functions to work with `NSTimer`. I found this:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26983

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/49465#49465

But solution seems a bit twisty...

What I am trying to make in code, which doesn't work of course, is something like this:

```
protocol TimerHelper {
    var timer:NSTimer { get set }
}

extension TimerHelper {

    func startTimer() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: self.updateTimer(), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateTimer() {
       print("Timer updated.")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, TimerHelper {

    var timer: NSTimer = NSTimer()
    func start() {
        startTimer()
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: doesn't work means? is there an error specifically?

Comment: I am sorry the error is literally: `Argument type 'Self' does not conform to expected type 'Anyobject'.` But in my opinion this current error is not important - there were bunch of errors for more situations I tried according to posts I found or other examples etc. This code was supposed only to illustrate my idea. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Never do:

```
... = NSTimer()
```

Instead create the variable as an optional. You want to invalidate and destroy the timer, and you never want a timer that hasn't been configured properly or invalidated.

Your extension is inappropriate because it deals with aspects not covered by the protocol itself. You should have 2 protocols, where the second protocol extends the first and is called something like `TimerActivation`. It defines the functions and the extension implements them.

This doesn't change what you need to do in the VC to use the timer, but it makes your type system clean, effective, reusable and extensible.

For the self referential part you need to look at `#selector`, I haven't tried it inside a protocol before, should be interesting...

It may be wiser to supply the selector, or an invocation, to the start function, because there is little point in a protocol extension implementing the selector when the protocol is so general. But, I suppose you may want to add other child protocols with extensions which provide other implementations so you can mixin functionality, interesting idea...

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes I am aware of the need to proper initiate and invalidate NSTimer and so on. The code I posted should only illustrate my basic idea of relations. Anyway to key issue is for me the #selector part. I'm not sure I understand you well with last paragraph. What I'm looking for now is basically extension which I would be able to use in other classes with minimum amount of code = this in fact means principle of inheriting for me, but Swift is protocol oriented. For example: two UIViewControllers use same mechanism for timers like same alert or something like that...

Comment: So perhaps you don't want timers as such, you want command objects which contain a timer and other logic...

Comment: Yes it also can be said like that, but I just thought that instead of creating new instance for every use of Timer or Helper or whatever, it might be more useful to share same functionality via universal protocol-extension to simulate inheriting...so is it wrong idea?